# Civicrm invoice number reset

Tags: civicontribute, invoice

We have activated the contribute form within our CIVI.

We wondered: with the arrival of the new year, when there will be the need to restart from 1 with the invoice numbering, do we have to do some operation or will the system restart automatically?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It will not restart automatically, the requirement to restart from 1 (with a year somewhere in the invoice number?) is depending on countries AFAIK :-)

So what you need to do first thing in the new year is navigate to  Administer>CiviContribute>CiviContribute Component Settings and update the invoice prefix (and the credit notes prefix if you need that too).

Comment: I don't think there is likely to be any country specific requirement for this, but that its something that an organisation may set as policy. I certainly would not reset as its good accounting practice to have invoice numbers unique, but using the prefix is a good way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In our country the invoice numbering restarts every January.

Is there a way to reset it manually?

Comment: See my answer above? That is how to do it manually :-)

Comment: I tried but updating the prefix does not activate the invoice numbering reset

Comment: There won't be any way to reset the actual Contribution ID as that is the database row value and hence has to be unique

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. We are try to find a way to reset the invoice number, not the contribution ID, even if currently the first value is generated by the second, which also creates potential holes in the billing